# Sync Google Calendar to Outlook 2010

Tags: google-calendar, microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to sync (two way) my outlook to my Google calendar, but I don't want to use outlook as my mail client.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: There are some free and paid-plugins that do this, but a google search would help you more than posting off-topic questions on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it but [gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/) claims to allow you to synchronise Outlook calendars, contacts, notes, and tasks with your Google account. It'll set you back $20 though.

In addition, it'll also support synchronization between Outlook and Toodledo, Pocket Informant Online, Evernote, Dropbox, Simplenote and Nozbe.

For email, you'd have to [configure Outlook to access Google's IMAP and SMTP server](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_get_gmail.htm). Since you don't want email, you can just ignore those steps.